# Compiling OS from source

Tags: operating-systems, source-code

I downloaded the [Python OS](http://python-os.info/en/) source code (the compiled ISO torrent didn't work) and I got a bunch of folders with makefiles and things in them. I'm trying to figure out a way to run this preferably on a USB flash drive. The site has no documentation and half of it is in Russian. running `Make` inthe distrib folder gives me the error: `Makefile:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

You can see what I downloaded [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!CtpxyDwQ!U37IR4RjkwYsLcHqMTm3I_bYL040x1OFHYT4z-l6mxM)

Comment: Has anyone tried this. If you're afraid of a virus the original page I downloaded from is [this page](http://python-os.info/#source)

Comment: You need to wait for a response.

Comment: I have been waiting. Is it wrong for me to post the original link? Most questions I've asked on SO sites have been answered almost immediately so I decided this one might have people worried I'd posted an infected file. @Ramhound

Comment: We are not a programming website.  Your inability to compile something isn't really a Superuser question, its a programming question, because the Make file clearly is bugged.